# Torch Insert tensors of different dimension into a table

Tags: lua, lua-table, torch

I'm trying to insert tensors of different dimensions into a lua table. But the insertion is writing the last tensor to all the previous elements in the table.

MWE:

```
require 'nn';

char = nn.LookupTable(100,10,0,1)
charRep = nn.Sequential():add(char):add(nn.Squeeze())

c = {}
c[1] = torch.IntTensor(5):random(1,100)
c[2] = torch.IntTensor(2):random(1,100)
c[3] = torch.IntTensor(3):random(1,100)
--This works fine
print(c)

charFeatures = {}
for i=1,3 do
  charFeatures[i] =  charRep:forward(c[i])
  --table.insert(charFeatures, charRep:forward(c[i]))
  -- No difference when table.insert is used
end
--This fails
print(charFeatures)
```

Maybe i haven't understood how tables work in Lua. But this code copies the last tensor to all previous `charFeatures` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not related with tables, but is very common in Torch though. When you call the `forward` method on a neural net, its state value `output` is changed. Now when you save this value into `charFeatures[i]` you actually create a reference from `charFeatures[i]` to `charRep.output`. Then in the next iteration of the loop `charRep.output` is modified and consequently all the elements of `charFeatures` are modified too, since they point to the same value which is `charRep.output`.

Note that this behavior is the same as when you do

```
a = torch.Tensor(5):zero()
b = a
a[1] = 0
-- then b is also modified
```

Finally to solve your problem you should clone the output of the network:

```
charFeatures[i] = charRep:forward(c[i]):clone()
```

And all will work as expected!